# make a combination of records on the basis of a column value using sql

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2012

Given a following table:

```
**Title**    |    **Value** 
Color    |    Red  
Color    |    Green  
Color    |    Blue  
Size     |    Small  
Size     |    Medium  
Size     |    Large
```

Now i want to make all possible combination related to Color and Size.

Output should be look like this:

```
**Size** | **Color**
Small | Red  
Small | Green  
Small | Blue  
Medium | Red  
Medium | Green  
Medium | Blue  
Large | Red  
Large | Green  
Large | Blue
```

So, there's 9 possible Combinations (Variations) with color and size attributes

How is this possible in SQL Server Database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a cross-self-join of your table, restricting one side to be only color records and the other side to be only size records.

```
SELECT
    t2.Value,
    t1.Value
FROM yourTable t1
CROSS JOIN yourTable t2
WHERE
    t1.Title = 'Color' AND
    t2.Title = 'Size'
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN t2.Value = 'Small'  THEN 1
         WHEN t2.Value = 'Medium' THEN 2
         WHEN t2.Value = 'Large'  THEN 3 END,
    CASE WHEN t1.Value = 'Red'    THEN 1
         WHEN t1.Value = 'Green'  THEN 2
         WHEN t1.Value = 'Blue'   THEN 3 END;
```

Note that you can omit the lengthy `ORDER BY` clause if you don't really need to present your data in the order which you showed us.  For example, if you have an application or presentation layer consuming this data, then ordering it might not matter or be necessary.

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: can you please help me out in case of dynamic attribute values? i mean color, size, style etc... these attributes can be dynamic and I didn't even know how much it will be...

Comment: @Hamza I stand by Gordon's comment 100%.  If you have a substantially different question, then ask a new one.  Stack Overflow is not a blog site where questions morph and drag on.  In fact, the site was created to _avoid_ this.

Comment: ok. Tim, Really Thanks... I'll ask another question in term of dynamic approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cross join`:

```
select s.size, c.color
from (select value as size from t where title = 'size') s cross join
     (select value as color from t where title = 'color') c;
```

Actually, you don't need the subqueries:

```
select ts.value as size, tc.value as color
from t ts cross join
     t tc
where ts.title = 'size' and tc.title = 'color';
```

Comment: I have dynamic attributes in term of Size, Color, Weight etc... every attributes have it's dynamic values which i have mentioned above in the question. So, can you elaborate more clearly about this 
in dynamic structure

Comment: @Hamza Gordon's query (and mine) should work with any number of sizes and colors, so long as they don't appear in duplicate.

Comment: @Hamza . . . That is not the question that you asked ("Now i want to make all possible combination related to Color and Size.").  If you have *another* question, then ask it as *another* question.  This question appears to have been answered (if you change this question, you will invalidate the answers which will draw downvotes to people who tried to help you).